# SetValue control ngui-auto-complet in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I would like to know if I can load data into an input as I do in a select when searching.
What I am doing: I am saving the data of a form, after saving the form, I make a query of the stored data and mapping them in the corresponding fields, I have not had any problems, until I run into my **`ngui-auto-type`** field complete loads **[Object, Object]** when passing the complete object, but if I only add the name, it shows it as it is.

But the problem is when editing the field does not load the data of the field only the name.

My field code:

```
  <div class="form-group" id="2">
    <label class="textBlod">Profession: </label>
       <span class="textBigRed">*</span>
        <input ngui-auto-complete [source]="dataProfession" value-property-name="Id" formControlName="Profession"
                  display-property-name="Description" list-formatter="Description" class="form-control"  [attr.disabled]="blockForm">
  </div>
```

This is the way in which I reload the data in the field after consulting the information:

```
 this.representativeComponent.dataProfession.forEach(elementProfe => {
      if (elementProfe.ClassPro === data.IdProfession) {
        this.representativeComponent.representativeComponentFrom.get('Profession').setValue(elementProfe);
      }
    });
```

This is shown in the field by sending the object as shown in the code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngui-auto-complete` requires you to use `ngModel` and `source`.

- ngModel, any, variable that autocomplete result is assigned to
- source, array or string, required. data source for dropdown list

Just add `[(ngModel)]="yourVar"` and your code should work.

More about [ngui-auto-complete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngui/auto-complete#attributes).

> Update for Reactive Forms

For Reactive Forms use `[formControl]="yourVar"` insted of `[(ngModel)]="yourVar"`.

Comment: i use Reactive Forms

Comment: all examples have [source] :(

Comment: You need bouth _All options are optional except ngModel and source_

Comment: Look what appears when you implemented the ngModel, .... `It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7`

Comment: I think i found it. Use `[formControl]="yourVar"` insted of `[(ngModel)]="yourVar"`